# Angular Material - CSS not working on component's inner elements

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using **MatExpansionPanel** from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview). When I inspected the generated html I got something like this

```html
<mat-expansion-panel _ngcontent-lnt-c367="" class="mat-expansion-panel ng-tns-c278-0 mat-expanded ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-expanded="true">
   <div role="region" class="mat-expansion-panel-content ng-tns-c278-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-bodyExpansion" id="cdk-accordion-child-0" aria-labelledby="mat-expansion-panel-header-0" style="visibility: visible;">
       <div class="mat-expansion-panel-body ng-tns-c278-0"> 
         ...
       </div>
   </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

The first div (with the class mat-expansion-panel-content) has a lot of spacing that I want to remove. but before that I tried the css selector like the following

```css
ion-menu mat-expansion-panel {
    background-color: green; /* works */
}
ion-menu mat-expansion-panel .mat-expansion-panel-content {
    background-color: red; /* doesn't work */
    margin: 0;
}
```

I tried inspecting the div to check if some other style uses `!important` I found out that my css is not present at all.
Any clue why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 methods you can use to access those inner css selectors inside other components.

**Method 1 - global stylesheet**

First you can give mat-expantion-panel a class name, then you can access that with your global .s(css) but i would only do that if its something you are gonna repeat.

example:

```
// component.html
...
<mat-expantion-panel class="bg-red">...</mat-expantion-panel>
...
// styles.scss (not component.scss)
mat-expantion-panel {
   &.bg-red {
     .mat-expansion-panel-content {
       background-color: red; /* should now work */
       margin: 0;
     }
   }
}
```

**Method 2 - use ng-deep**

use ::ng-deep, this means you bleed that css out into global space (breaking component styling isolation), so to avoid it changes something unintended use the pattern with the `:host` in you component.scss

Note: this is the preferred method. If you care about component isolation, cause then the style changes stays with component.

Example:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  // you can no target the inner / generated css selectors from here.
  .mat-expansion-panel-content {
     background-color: red; /* should now work */
     margin: 0;
   } 
}
```

**Method 3 - viewEncapsulation.none (rarely use / prefer not to)**

Use Change the viewEncapsulation.none on your component. This means you bleed the entire css into the global space. Only usecases where i can come up with for a reason to use this if you make a UI library else i would not go with this approach