# CSS changes to Table Row tag overridden by Table Data tags (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to make some changes to rows of a table (say background color) but those do not seem to apply. When I check developer tools of my browser, I see that those are overridden by another tag (body .ui-table .ui-table-tbody>tr>td ) which I can't find in my code.
This is the opening tag of the table row:

```
<tr class='flow-row' [bSelectableRow]="item">
```

The CSS is as:

```
.flow-row {
  height: 28px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This is the style that I find on hovering over a table data using inspect:

```
body .ui-table .ui-table-tbody>tr>td{
    background-color : #fff;
}
```

If I change any color on this tag, it gets applied to the whole rows but the changes to .flow-row class are overridden by this.

I expected that changes to background-color in the .flow-row class would apply that particular background color to the rows of the table but it doesn't happen.

Comment: Try increasing the selectivity. e,g body .ui-table .ui-table-tbody>tr.flow-row>td and body .ui-table .ui-table-tbody>tr.flow-row

Comment: You just need to target it, I made an answer a short while back that covers this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75781831/1805974 though its for an expantion panel, but its the same you have 3 methods to set those styes